# Interaction between QMainWindow class and QDialogue class

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a GUI app. I have a main window(*QMainWindow*) which pops up when the app is executed.

```
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This window has some buttons. When I click a button here, another window which is of *QDialog* is popped up. The logic of the button is

```
void MainWindow::on_InsertButton_pressed()
{
    libinsert lib ;
    lib.setModal(false);
    lib.exec();
}
```

***Question***: I have a socket in the *QMainWindow* class, whenever I receive a message there I need to send it to the *QDialogue* window and display it in a *QLineEdit*. With the above logic, even after I set *QDialogue* to *nonmodal*, I am not able to interact with the *QMainWindow* when the *QDialogue* window is open. I tried *lib.show()* instead of *lib.exec()*, but with this, when I click the button the *QMainWindow* class the *QDialogue* window does not pop up.

Please advice me what is the best method to communicate from the background window the the foreground window?

Comment: You should make use if the signal-and-slot mechanism in Qt. Have a look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can looks like

```
void MainWindow::on_InsertButton_pressed()
{
    libinsert lib ;
    connect( this, SIGNAL( messageReceived( QString ), &lib, SLOT( letsChangeLineEdit( QString ) ) ) );
    lib.setModal(false);
    lib.exec();
}
```

Of course you should implement your signal and slot. QString in signal slot arguments is target string to show in dialog.
Hope that will clear for you.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented the interaction by adding a signal in the QMainWIndow and passing some data in the signal(), which is received at the  QDialogue class

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainWindow::on_InsertButton_pressed()`slot you are creating a local variable libinsert lib  which gets destroyed when it gets out of scope, i.e. when the slot execution finishes. If you use `lib.exec()` the execution waits for the dialog execution to return so you see the dialog, but can't interact with the main window until you close it. When you use `lib.show()`, your dialog is shown, execution continues and exits the slot right away, at which point the lib gets destroyed and you don't see it any more (depending on your configuration this may be fast enough that it looks like it newer gets shown in the first place).

One solution is to have a pointer to your dialog as a member of MainWindow class (add `libinsert* lib;` in `MainWindow.h)`, and initialize it in your Mainwindow constructor like this:

```
`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
      ui->setupUi(this);
      lib = new libinsert(this);
      lib->setModal(false);
 }`
```

Then in `MainWindow::on_InsertButton_pressed()` you only need to call `QWidget::show()` method, i.e. like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_InsertButton_pressed()
{
    lib->show();
}
```

Now, if what you are trying to achieve is to have a dialog pop-up every time the message is received , and display the message, first you will need to have a public method(or slot) in your `libinsert` class which updates the text in your `QLineEdit`, for example

```
void libinsert::onMessageReceived(QString message)
{
     // Update the text and show the dialog to avoid having to call show() 
     //   explicitly from MainWindow.
     ui->lineEdit->setText(message);
     show(); 
 }
```

and then either call this method directly, when you receive the message, with:

```
lib->onMessageReceived(message);
```

or connect a signal, emitted when message is received, to it with something like this (in MainWindow constructor):

```
 connect( this, SIGNAL( messageReceived( QString ), &lib, SLOT( onMessageReceived( QString ) ) ) );
```